# ActivityNotFoundException when trying to start twitter app

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, activitynotfoundexception

I coded an intent to start twitter app but it's throwing `ActivityNotFoundException` even when I have the layest version of twitter installed.

**My Code**

```
Intent twitShare = new Intent()
                        .setType("text/plain")
                        .setPackage("com.twitter.android")
                        .setData(Uri.parse(url))
                        .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    startActivity(twitShare);
```

Please , what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `setData()` from your `Intent`. `ACTION_SEND` does not use the data facet of the `Uri`. Follow [the instructions in the `ACTION_SEND` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) to supply your data to send, either via `EXTRA_TEXT` or `EXTRA_STREAM`.

Comment: Thanks. that fixed it.